# clojure - could not locate errors?

Tags: oauth, clojure, leiningen

Iam trying for HOURS now and cant figure out the problem.
Iam new to clojure and try to make a simple flickr client. 
But I have this problem with different libraries... I think I make a general mistake.

At the moment I try to use oauth with this lib: https://github.com/mattrepl/clj-oauth

```
lein new projectname
```

and my project.clj looks like this:

```
(defproject flickr "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
          :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
               [clj-oauth "1.4.0"]])
```

After adding the clj-oauth2 I run:

```
  lein deps
```

And my core.clj:

```
  (ns flickr.core)
  (require ['oauth.client :as 'oauth])


 (def consumer-key "0000")
 (def consumer-secret "0000")

 (def consumer (oauth.client/make-consumer <consumer-token>
                               <consumer-token-secret>                            
                               "http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token"
                               "http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/access_token"
                               "http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize"
                                :hmac-sha1))
```

When I now try to run it:

```
   lein run
```

I get:

```
   FileNotFoundException Could not locate oauth/client__init.class or oauth/client.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:432)
```

Does anyone has an idea where the problem is?
Also also downloaded the oauth source from the github repo, built it and added it to my $PATH variable but still the same error.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `lein run` looks for a main namespace, whose name must be specified in `project.clj` using the `:main` key; **add `:main flickr.core` there**.

Then you need a `-main` function in `flickr.core`.  Change your namespace declaration and add the function as follows:

```
(ns flickr.core
  (:require [clj-oauth2.client :as oauth]))

(defn -main []
  (println oauth/get-access-token))
```

Then,

```
$ lein run
;=> #<client$get_access_token clj_oauth2.client$get_access_token@4c9549af>
```

That worked for me as a sort of "namespace smoke test," and you should be able to go from there.

(As a final note, your development will go much faster if you test these sorts of things in the REPL rather than using 'lein run.')

Answer (score 1):

It appears there's confusion with your dependencies.  According to Clojars, the library you're using `clj-oauth2` is this GitHub project https://github.com/DerGuteMoritz/clj-oauth2, not the one you link to in the question.

If you want the latest `clj-oauth`, then the dependency should be `[clj-oauth "1.4.0"]` (for the latest version).  If you need `clj-oauth2` then the above GitHub link should be the reference.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Iam actually using clj-oauth. The clj-oauth2 was from a previous test.